# Running mix ecto.create command for creating a database in a Phoenix project with a postgresql instaled by brew

Tags: macos, elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I have installed postgres using package manager (brew). After starting the service as background and run this to create database on Phoenix I got this error:

```
dedeco@MacBook-Pro-Dedeco> mix ecto.create                                                                                            

23:57:56.112 [error] GenServer #PID<0.242.0> terminating
** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28000 (invalid_authorization_specification) role "postgres" does not exist
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:87: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
** (Mix) The database for Hello.Repo couldn't be created: killed
```

Answer (score 3):

If you installed Postgres using homebrew, it probably was created a SUPERUSER using your operating system (OS) USER, like your name.

So you need a postgres user, you must create using these commands:

```
dedeco@MacBook-Pro-Dedeco> psql postgres                                                                                                              
psql (12.2)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 dedeco    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}

postgres=# CREATE USER postgres SUPERUSER;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=#
```

Another option is changing the postgres user int the file `config/dev.exs` (or prod.exs, it depends which env you are) as follow:

```
# Configure your database
config :hello, Hello.Repo,
  username: "<USER_NAME>",
  password: "<PASSWORD>",
  database: "hello_dev",
  hostname: "localhost",
  show_sensitive_data_on_connection_error: true,
  pool_size: 10
```